# Load only needed points to map from PostGIS in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, postgis

I'm loading a lot of points, polygons and lines from a PostGIS database to a google map. If I load the entire DB, it'll kill the browser, so I'm looking for a way to load only in the area the user can see. Is there a way to accomplish that?

I'm using GMaps3 to show the data, RGeo, PostGIS and Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may load the points via ajax.

Observe the `bounds_changed`-event of the map, send the bounds to the server and let the server respond with the points(filtered by the given bounds). How exactly the filtering works I can't tell you exactly, because I'm not familiar with PostGIS, but [ST_CONTAINS](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Contains.html) appears to be the method you need.

However, a user may zoom to a very low level, in this case you will still get a large amount of points, but you may additionally restrict the loading of the points to a higher zoom-level.

Another option(I would prefer it): Import the data into a FusionTable and use a FusionTableLayer, this would give a much better performance.